# Example of RestSharp ASYNC client.ExecuteAsync<T> () works

Tags: c#, restsharp

Could someone please help me modify the code below:

```cs
client.ExecuteAsync(request, response => {
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
});
```

Basically I want to use ExecuteAsync method above but don't want to print but return response.Content to the caller.

Is there any easy way to achieve this?

I tried this but doesnt' work:

```cs
public T Execute<T>(RestRequest request) where T : new()
{
    var client = new RestClient();
    client.BaseUrl = BaseUrl;
    client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(_accountSid, _secretKey);
    request.AddParameter("AccountSid", _accountSid, ParameterType.UrlSegment); // used on every request
    var response = client.ExecuteAsync(request, response => {
        return response.data);
    });
}
```

The above code is from
https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp

Answer (score 38):

There's the thing... you can't return an asynchronously delivered value, because your calling method will already have returned. Blocking the caller until you have a result defeats the point of using ExecuteAsync. In this case, I'd return a `Task<string>` (assuming response.Content is a string):

```
Task<string> GetResponseContentAsync(...)
{
  var tcs=new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
  client.ExecuteAsync(request, response => {
    tcs.SetResult(response.Content);
  });
  return tcs.Task;
}
```

Now, when the task completes, you have a value. As we move to c#5 async/await, you should get used to stating asynchrony in terms of `Task<T>` as it's pretty core.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

Comment: could you please elaborate "you can't return an asynchronously delivered value"

Answer (score 5):

With the help of @spender, this is what i got:

You can add new file in RestSharp project, and add this code:

```
public partial class RestClient
{
    public Task<IRestResponse<T>> ExecuteAsync<T>(IRestRequest request)
    {
        var tcs=new TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse<T>>();

        this.ExecuteAsync(request, response => 
            {
                tcs.SetResult(
                    Deserialize<T>(request, response)
                );
            });

    return tcs.Task;
    }       
}
```

This will practically return the full response, with status code and everything, so you can check if the status of the response is OK before getting the content, and you can get the content with:

```
response.Content
```

Comment: What namespace is `Deserialize` in?

Answer (score 1):

From reading the code it looks like you want to use `ExecuteAsGet` or `ExecuteAsPost` instead of the async implementation.

Or maybe just Execute- not sure exactly what type Client is.

Comment: This question is specific to RESTSharp, don't think ExecuteGet is available.

Comment: According to the code that you linked to, it is defined here (ExecuteAsGet, ExecuteAsPost, and just plain old Execute): https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/RestClient.Sync.cs

Comment: It depends on the platform. RestSharp for Windows Phone only contains the async methods

Answer (score 1):

At some point, there was a bunch of overloads introduced that support `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` and had the word "Task" in them. They  can be awaited (like `HttpClient`'s methods).

For instance:

- `ExecuteTaskAsync(request)` (returns `Task<IRestResponse>`)
- `ExecuteGetTaskAsync(request)` (returns `Task<IRestResponse>`)
- `ExecuteGetTaskAsync<T>(request)` (returns `Task<IRestResponse<T>>`)

Those then became deprecated in later v106 versions in favour of Task-support being the default I believe, e.g. the first one became `client.ExecuteAsync(request)`.

So these days you can just do:

```cs
var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
return response.Content;
```